# Saving SpringLiquibase's SQL statement for later use

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

If I run Liquibase by Maven then I use "mvn liquibase:updateSQL", but how to save statement using SpringLiquibase?

Comment: see this https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app

Answer (score 0):

You can save the updateSQL script to an external file using the parameter `-Dliquibase.migrationSqlOutputFile=xxxx` while invoking the command. See more info at : https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-updatesql.html

Or you could specify the file name in your maven `pom.xml` using  in your Liquibase configuration and adding a maven goal.

If you are asking to use a Spring property for Liquibase like `spring.liquibase.change-log` then I'm not sure if one exists for `migrationSqlOutputFile` like `spring.liquibase.migrationSqlOutputFile`, but you could try it.